# Adding significant result as superscripts, new column for other stat, and transpose the group in tbl_summary

Tags: gtsummary

I love `gtsummary` package. After a while playing with it, I have finished my almost-ideal-table of mine. However, are there anyway I can add significant superscripts to values in tbl_summary (both manually or automatically)? Also, is it possible to add a new stat column to show something like PSE (I can calculate it manually, but having a hard time to combine it into the summary table. Last but not least, is it possible to transpose the grouping from the `by` argument to the rows instead of column?

Thank you.

[Desired Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCEsj.png)

Comment: Can you please include an example of what you'd like the table to look like in the end?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response and sorry for the delay. I have uploaded the desired table. Is it possible to create something like this?